# Proper typing with Vue2 + vue-property-decorator + @vue/composition-api (TypeScript)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

Suppose a Vue component is written like

```
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
// ...

@Component({
   setup () {
      const { something } = useComposable();
      return { something }
   }
})
export default class DummyComponent extends Vue {
   doSomething(command: string) {
       this.something // issue
   }
}
```

Two issues here:

1. `TS2339: Property 'something' does not exist on type 'DummyComponent'.` and
2. `this.something` is not typed.

Adding an index signature (`[x: string]: any;`) seems like a bad workaround to satisfy the linter / tsc and setting the return type of the setup method does not solve the issue #1. Is there **the** right way to do it or am I mixing stuff that's not supposed to be mixed. I'm sure the awesome Vue devs thought of that?

What's the proper way to satisfy `tsc`?